# ASP .NET WebAPI - приложение перезапускается 2 раза после публикации

Tags: c#, iis, webapi

После публикации через WebDeploy приложение Web API на IIS перезапускается 2 раза. С помощью [рефлексии в Global.asax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194) удалось установить причину перезапусков:

1. _shutDownMessage=Change Notification for critical directories.
   bin dir change or directory rename
2. _shutDownMessage=CONFIG change
   HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown

При публикации также пробовал использовать [AppOffline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing), но тогда в логе такая запись:

1._shutDownMessage=Change in App_Offline.htm
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown

2._shutDownMessage=Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename

Нормальное ли это поведение? Хотел бы отметить, что global.asax предкомпилируется при публикации, используется OWIN.

Обновлено: заметил, что при перезапуске пула иногда приложение перезапускается 2 раза:

1. Change in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5e3789de\e7cc3cd0\hash\hash.web
   HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
   HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

Внутри этого файла 70b91c61ae007ebd;1505

2. CONFIG change
   HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
   CONFIG change
   HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

из-за чего меняется конфиг и файл во временной папке?

Comment: По-хорошему перед публикацией приложение надо останавливать...